# What song is this on the Code Geass soundtrack?

Tags: music, code-geass

My friends and I are racking through the Code Geass soundtrack trying to find out which song this is, and we're stumped:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgGG2F4Izf4

Comment: Yes closing my question after 7 years was definitely a good use of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The song is "Pure Feelings", Track 18 in the second OST for R2.

the particular piece that plays in the scene you point to begins roughly at 1:34 of the song